# using regex noun filters for typing specific codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want type specific product codes to textarea
but my code allows only type one letter and if I press another key it deletes last letter.

I want user allow only type these codes what are in regexNounFilters

```
$('#toFile').on('keypress', function(e) {
  onInput(e);
});

const regexNounFilters = [<?php
  $data = $pdo->query("SELECT PRODUCT_CODE AS code, ENDING AS ec FROM test")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  foreach ($data as $key) {
    $separator = ($key != end($data)) ? ", " : '';
    $std = "/^(" . $key->code . ")([a-zA-Z0-9]{" . $key->ec . "})$/";
    echo $std.$separator;
  }
?>];

//  const regexNounFilters = [/^(AAAB)([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$/, /^(BBBBBC)([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})$/];

const extractNouns = string => string.split('\n').filter(line => regexNounFilters.some(re => line.trim().toUpperCase().match(re));

function onInput({
  target
}) {
  target.value = extractNouns(target.value).join('\n');
}
```

This code must allow only type in textarea AAAB product code with 7 digit/letter long..
And BBBBBC with 9 digit/letter long..

Example:

```
AAAB0000001
AAAB0000002
AAAB0000003
AAAB0000004
BBBBBC000000001
BBBBBC000000002
BBBBBC000000003
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/SlfQNt/1  `/AAAB.{0,7}|BBBBBC.{0,9}/`

Comment: 1) Maybe you'll try reformate SQL to `SELECT PRODUCT_CODE AS code, ENDING AS ec FROM test WHERE LENGTH('code') = 7`; 2) As I can see using both filters in code.

Comment: @bassxzero it doesnt solve problem, but its cleaner format of regex.
@Kosmos full length of product code "AAAB" is 11. `AAAB0000001` So I think my sql query is best way to do.